# MAC PackageMaker preinstall/postinstall script to get original *.pkg file directory

Tags: macos, bash, packagemaker

How do I get the original *.pkg file directory when install it?

I have created a pkg file, and put it with another file(like `test.txt`) into a same folder, like ~/Desktop/test

And when install pkg file, I want it to copy the "test.txt" file to ~/Library folder.
So I add preinstall/postinstall script into pkg file to copy the "test.txt" file.
I try to get the directory use

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

But it will return the tmp directory

```
/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.G5GFI6/Scripts/com.myApp.testApp.pkg.o5k2nE
```

not the original pkg directory `(~/Desktop/test)`

Has anybody know how to get the original directory when install?

Comment: why don't you embed the plist with your package? Also plist should be created by your app, not package

Comment: The plist file may be changed in the later time, it would result in create a new related pkg frequently when plist file changed. BTW: it may not only plist file to be copied.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 14):

You've created a flat package? Have you tried looking at the parameters passed to the postinstall script?

```
$0 - Script path
$1 - Package path
$2 - Target location
$3 - Target volume`
```

Parameter $1 should give you what you're looking for.

Copied from [old bundle style format information](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), but still seems to apply to newer flat packages.

Answer (score 3):

This [Mac Installers Blog](http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html) has some useful posts about Packagemaker including details about the usage and solutions to common problems.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
pkgpath=\`dirname "$PACKAGE_PATH"\`
```

will give you the path to the package in the variable `$pkgpath`.